# If $A$ is a subset of $B$, then $A = B$. What is the direct proof?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $x\in A$, then that should mean $x\in B$. So wouldn't that make $A = B$ by the definition of subset relations?

Comment: It's false. Have you tried any examples?

Comment: Subset is “smaller” than the whole set, and even if it can be *equal*, it can also be *strictly smaller*. For example, the set of all *even* integers is a (strict) subset of the set of all integers.

Comment: $A = B$ is equivalent to $A \subset B$ AND $B \subset A$, and in general one of these conditions can hold without both being true. For instance, $\{1,2\} \subsetneq \{1,2,3\}$.

Answer (score 2):

No, because there might exist a $b\in B$ with $b\notin A$.